# JQuery Scroll Animation Causes Objects To Load Invisible Not Visible No Opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've used the following code to make objects fade on scroll. It works well, except that when the page loads, the objects are not visible. You have to scroll a little bit to make them visible. Then, the scrolling works to reduce opacity as intended. Any idea why? I've used bootstrap, jquery, and you can run the snippet below to test the issue.

Thanks, 
Will

```js
var target = $('.fade');
    var targetHeight = 400;

    $(document).scroll(function(e){
        var scrollPercent = (targetHeight - window.scrollY) / targetHeight;
        if(scrollPercent >= 0){
            target.css('opacity', scrollPercent);
        }
    });
```

```css
/*!
Theme Name: Frozen Land
Author: Will Caulfield
Author URI: http://caulfield.co/
Description: Description
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: LICENSE
Text Domain: frozenland.co
*/
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: calc(70px + 0.3vw);
  margin: 10px 0px 25px 0px;
}

main {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f9c4cc), to(#f27aaa));
  background: linear-gradient(#f9c4cc, #f27aaa);
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatIce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-15px);
            transform: translatey(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatIce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-15px);
            transform: translatey(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatText {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
            transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatText {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
            transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatLand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-5px);
            transform: translatey(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes floatLand {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-5px);
            transform: translatey(-5px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}

.hero-ice {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
          transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatIce 6s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: floatIce 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.hero-text {
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
          transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.hero-land {
  width: 250px;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
          transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: floatText 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes caret-float {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(7px);
            transform: translatey(7px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes caret-float {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(7px);
            transform: translatey(7px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
            transform: translatey(0px);
  }
}

.hero-scroll {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0px);
          transform: translatey(0px);
  -webkit-animation: caret-float 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: caret-float 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Googl Fonts -->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-REHJTs1r2ErKBuJB0fCK99gCYsVjwxHrSU0N7I1zl9vZbggVJXRMsv/sLlOAGb4M" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Scripts -->

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
        <section class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="hero w-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center fade">
                <img class="hero-ice" src="img/ice-cream.png" />
                <h1 class="hero-text">Frozen Land</h1>
                <img class="hero-land" src="img/land.png" />
            </div>
            <i class="hero-scroll far fa-caret-square-down fade"></i>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div>
                z
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div>
                z
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
   

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom Scripts -->

    <script src="/js/custom.js"></script>

    <script>
        

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The default css styling applied to the `.fade` element has an opacity of 0, from the rule with `.fade:not(.show)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `fade` applies `opacity: 0;`, replace with other class name in HTML and in jQuery selector

Comment: Thanks, Narek. For everyone else: Bootstrap applies the class `fade` which has a default `opacity: 0;`